# How to create a single color pie chart in Tableau

Tags: tableau-desktop

I am creating a pie chart based on different room types in the market , when I take out the color marks , the pie chart would be just one color but without border showing [pie chart with just one color](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gheGs.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even if you don't put anything in the color mark, you can change the color and color of the borders from there.
Click to the color mark and change the border from **"Automatic"** to the color you want for the borders :)